# how does rollback works in automotive software download?

Tags: automotive

I am trying to figure out way to upgrade software over bus (can/ethernet). While doing this, Safe state suggest to rollback to previous sw.
Please can anyone help me understand how and what are the ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to roll back is to have enough flash storage, to store the old applications, until the new ones are proven to work.

As applications across ECUs depend on each other, some coordinator, often in a central gateway, has to coordinate that.

In a first step, this coordinator downloads the software release for the whole vehicle, stores it in local memory and does some authenticity and integrity checks.

If not already stored, it can also download the last release, which is flashed currently to it's local space.
The other alternative is to have a second flash area in the ECUs for that, which is usually more expensive.

Then the coordinator ensures that the vehicle is in a safe state, e.g. propulsion system off, no-one inside and doors locked.

If this is ensured, it uses the normal flash procedures to flash all ECUs with the cached software.

After that, it checks every ECU to ensure that flashing was successful.

If yes, it can discard what it stored.

Else, if the ECUs do not just switch back to an internal copy, it flashes the old application again.

For sure, there is a risk that this also fails, why one might want to have this two flash sections in each ECU.

However, the latter is not realistic for smaller ECUs like LIN slaves.